# Add additional value to the newest record (but show all records)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group, sql-view

I have to create view in MariaDB which contains all data from `states` table:

```
| id | user_id | state |
```

But to the newest record for each user (based on the highest id of state for each user). I have to also add column`is_newest` and set it to true (`1`) - rest of records should get false (`0`).

Is this possible to do in query?

Comment: More efficient:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MariaDB 10.3 or higher, you can use `row_number()`:

```
create view states_view as
select 
    id,
    user_id,
    state,
    (row_number() over(partition by user_id order by id desc) = 1) is_newest
from states
```

In earlier versions, where window functions are not available, one option is a to join an aggregate query:

```
create view states_view as
select 
    s.id,
    s.user_id,
    s.state,
    (s.id = m.max_id) is_newest
from states s
inner join (select user_id, max(id) max_id from states group by user_id) m
    on m.user_id = s.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select s.*, 
  (not exists(select 1 from states where user_id = s.user_id and id > s.id)) is_newest
from states s
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rHCg6ysWneXTo9dTE1rsP8/0).